# What is the range of the function $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 3}}{x-5}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I want to find the domain and range of the function $y =  \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 3}}{x-5}$. I found the domain to be $(-\infty,-3] \cup [-1, 5) \cup (5, \infty)$. I also found the inverse of the function:
$x = \frac{10y^2+4 \pm \sqrt{192y^2+4}}{2(y^2-1)}$ which is defined when $y \not= 1$ and $y \not= -1$. For this inverse to make sense $x$ needs to be a value in the domain, so I figure the range would be all values of $y$ such that:

$\frac{10y^2+4 \pm \sqrt{192y^2+4}}{2(y^2-1)} \leq -3$ or

$-1 \leq \frac{10y^2+4 \pm \sqrt{192y^2+4}}{2(y^2-1)} < 5$ or

$5 < \frac{10y^2+4 \pm \sqrt{192y^2+4}}{2(y^2-1)}$

Problem is, it's hard to solve for a explicit value of $y$ in the above inequalities, or at least I don't know how to do it. Is there a way to do it? Or maybe a completely different approach that will give me the range of the function? Symbolab says range should be $y \leq 0$ and $y > 1$, but I want to know how to get there.

Comment: $x^2+4x+3$ can be written as $(x-5)^2+14(x-5)+48$. So, if $x\in (5,\infty)$, then $y=\sqrt{48(\frac{1}{x-5}+\frac{7}{48})^2-\frac{1}{48}}$. If $x\in(-\infty,-3]\cup [-1,5)$, then $y =-\sqrt{48(\frac{1}{5-x}-\frac{7}{48})^2-\frac{1}{48}}$.

Answer (score 2):

The function is continuous. As $x$ approaches $5$ from the right, the numerator approaches $\sqrt{48}$ and the denominator approaches $0$ and stays positive, so the values are arbitrarily large and positive. As $x$ approaches $5$ from the left, the denominator approaches $0$ and is negative, so the values are arbitrarily large and negative. So we know the range will include intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Because $f(-1)=0$ and the values grow arbitrarily large and negative as you move along the interval $[-1,5)$, the range includes all negative values and $0$, so the range includes $(-\infty,0]$.

As $x\to\infty$, the function approaches $1$. Because  we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{(x+3)(x+1)}}{(x-5)},$$
for $x\gt 5$, each factor in the square root is greater than $x-5$, so this fraction is greater than $1$. Since $\lim_{x\to 5^+}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$, but $f(x)\gt 1$ for all $x\gt 5$, the range includes $(1,\infty)$.

The function never takes a positive value less than or equal to $1$. In order to take a value between $0$ and $1$, we need $x\gt 5$ (since the square root is always greater than or equal to $0$). So we would have
$$\begin{align*}
0\lt \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+3}}{x-5} &\leq 1\\
0\lt \sqrt{x^2+4x+3}&\leq x-5\\
0\lt x^2+4x+3 & \leq x^2-10x + 25\\
14x &\leq 22\\
x&\leq \frac{11}{7}.
\end{align*}$$
But $\frac{11}{7}\lt 5$, so we cannot both have $0\lt f(x)\leq 1$ *and* $x\gt 5$. Thus, the function takes no positive values less than or equal to $1$.

In summary: the function takes all values in $(-\infty,0]$, all values in $(1,\infty)$, and no values in $(0,1]$. So the range is $(-\infty,0]\cup (1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in class we haven't even seen what a continuos function is, or the Intermediate Value Theorem, so I don't think I can use those to justify it. I think the teachers was expecting us to do something along the lines of what I was doing, aka, find the inverse function and then see for what values the inverse function is defined and for which ones it isn't. At least that's what we've been doing in class so far.